# Relation between positive definite metric and full basis of a given operator

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's have some linear space with given indefinite metric. How the fact that metric isn't positive definite is connected with the fact that hermitian (due to the definition of hermicity in a given metric) operator doesn't have full basis of its eigenvectors?